# How to pass multiple secret nicknames in the ecs annotation

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ecs, spring-cloud-dataflow, aws-secrets-manager

I am using SCDF UI to launch pods on ECS cluster and I am passing all the required parameters from the task itself. My application uses two secrets , one for oracle and one for mongo.
I need to pass both the secret nicknames in job annotation.

I tried below approach but none of them worked.

a. deployer.app-test.kubernetes.jobAnnotations=ecs.o2c.secretsnicknames: 'MONGO_NICKNAME,ORACLE_NICKNAME'

b. deployer.app-test.kubernetes.jobAnnotations=ecs.o2c.secretsnicknames: "MONGO_NICKNAME,ORACLE_NICKNAME"

c. deployer.app-test.kubernetes.jobAnnotations=ecs.o2c.secretsnicknames: 'MONGO_NICKNAME+ORACLE_NICKNAME'

Please suggest how to do that using annotation.

Comment: You have added the `kubernetes` tag. Are you really using ECS (Elastic Container Service) or EKS (Elastic Kubernetes Service)?

Comment: @AndrewSkorkin  , I am using ECS. I am creating a task from spring cloud data flow UI and passing the required parameters. When the task is launched it creates a pod.           
     Here in yaml of the created pod the annotation is coming as below:                                                                                                               
  annotations:
        ecs.o2c.certificatesnicknames: services_dev
        **ecs.o2c.secretsnicknames: ORACLE_NICKNAME**
    But I need both the nicknames for my application to work without hardcoded mongo password.

Answer (score 0):

for me having same issue, trying to get two different secrets, i've used the following annotation:

```
ecs.o2c.secretsnicknames: "${SECRET1}, ${SECRET2}"
```

It should work. You only need to define the variables in the parameters section, such as:

```
parameters:
- name: SECRET1
  required: true
- name: SECRET2
  required: true
```

For your example, providing you have defined the MONGO_NICKNAME and the ORACLE_NICKNAME in the parameters section, you should have the following syntax:

```
ecs.o2c.secretsnicknames: "${MONGO_NICKNAME},${ORACLE_NICKNAME}"
```

If you inject somehow the strings directly, you should have:

```
ecs.o2c.secretsnicknames: "MongoNicknameString, OracleNicknameString"
```